# Why ScrollViewer overrides Grid row height in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I have a `ScrollViewer` which contains a `Grid` having two rows of height `'*'`

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"                    
                  Header="XYZ" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="0,10,0,0" 
                  Width="Auto" MinWidth="160"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  Style="{StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyle}">
        <ListBox Name="lstMentorGroups" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"                      
                  ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=MyCollection}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Style="{StaticResource MyListBoxStyle}">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
      </GroupBox>

      <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="160"          
                  Header="ABC" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  Style="{StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyle}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=List1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Style="{StaticResource MyListBoxStyle}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
          <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Prop1}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
      </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But at run time 1st Group box gets full height needed by its containing listbox that means it overrides Grid height * to auto

It works fine if I don't use scrollviewer it gives 50-50% height to each groupbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Grid` is placed in `ScrollViewe`r so it takes whole space how much it's controls requires. And I don't want to show vertical scroll bar.

I just set `Grid MaxHeight` to `ScrollViewer` ActualHeight

`MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=ScrollViewer, Path=ActualHeight}"`

Answer (score 0):

You need set the Height of the Grid if it's in the ScrollViewer, otherwise the Grid will have as much Height as it need, which means the ListBox in the Grid will get unlimited Height to display its items.

Comment: I don't want to give height to Grid that is why I am using scrollviewer

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the both rows takes the same height you should use the [SharedSizeGroupe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx)
So what you should do is:

```
<ScrollViewer>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"  />
    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"  />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"                    
              Header="XYZ" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="0,10,0,0" 
              Width="Auto" MinWidth="160"
              BorderThickness="0"
              Style="{StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyle}">
    <ListBox Name="lstMentorGroups" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"                      
              ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=MyCollection}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Style="{StaticResource MyListBoxStyle}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </GroupBox>

  <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" MinWidth="160"          
              Header="ABC" Margin="0,10,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              BorderThickness="0"
              Style="{StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyle}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=List1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Style="{StaticResource MyListBoxStyle}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Prop1}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it wasn't working. Then I found another solution for this.